# can't set permissions for edit and delete in drupal

Tags: drupal-6, permissions

I am working in drupal. I have to given the site administrator the permission to create, edit and delete news content (scrolltext).

I created a role named administrator and created an administrator user. I set the following permissions for the administratior:

- access administration menu
- create scrolltext content
- delete any scrolltext content
- delete own scrolltext content
- edit any scrolltext content
- edit own scrolltext content
- access scrolltext
- access administration pages

But when I log in as administrator in `content management -> create content -> scrolltext` I found there is no way to edit or delete scroolltext content.

Any idea why this might be happening?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create another administrator role , look at the admin role module
http://drupal.org/project/adminrole

Comment: no..i have to set permissions for this administrator persimissions

Answer (score 0):

Yo goto Administer > User management > Permissions Grant 'administer nodes'  to the role administrator